# Python Full Web Parsing

Tags: html, python-3.x

As of right now I'm attempting to make a simple music player app that streams music or video directly from a Youtube URL, and in order to do that I need the full download of the search page that's used to search for videos to stream. But I'm having some problems with the urlopen module in python 3, which is what I'm using to make the command application. It won't load the **ytd-app** tag on Youtube, which is what a good deal of the video and playlist references are put on when you first load the search. Anyone know what's going on, or know some type of workaround for it? Thanks!

My code so far:

```
BASICURL = "https://www.youtube.com/results?"
query = query.split()
ret = ""
stufffound = {}
for x in query:
    ret = ret + x + "+" 
ret = (ret[:len(ret)-1])

# URL BUILDER
if filtercriteria:
    URL = BASICURL + "sp={0}".format(filtercriteria) + "&search_query={0}".format(ret)
else:
    URL = BASICURL + "search_query={0}".format(ret)

query = urlopen(str(URL))
passdict = {}
def findvideosonpage(query,dictToAddTo):
    for x in (BS(urlopen(query)).read()).findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer'})
        dictToAddTo[query.index(x)] = x[href]
        print(x)
    return list([x for _,x in sorted(zip(dictToAddTo.values(), dictToAddTo.keys()))])
# Dictionary is meant to be converted into a list later to order the results
```